# How to work with a session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am making a page where you can manage your data for a website using php and phpmyadmin.
In this part I want this file,  `adminform.php` , to be able to update one or two columns: `Name` and `price` using a session.

[image of adminform.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCyZ2.png)

This is what I got:

Login.php

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
?>

<?
   // error_reporting(E_ALL);
   // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>

<html lang = "en">

   <head>

      <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

      <style>
         body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: black;
         }

         .form-signin {
            max-width: 330px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            color: yellow;
         }

         .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
         .form-signin .checkbox {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
         }

         .form-signin .checkbox {
            font-weight: normal;
         }

         .form-signin .form-control {
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
         }

         .form-signin .form-control:focus {
            z-index: 2;
         }

         .form-signin input[type="email"] {
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            border-color:#017572;
         }

         .form-signin input[type="password"] {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
            border-color:#017572;
         }

         h2{
            text-align: center;
            color: yellow;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body>

      <h2>Enter Username and Password</h2> 
      <div class = "container form-signin">

         <?php
            $msg = '';

            if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
               && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

               if ($_POST['username'] == 'administrator' && 
                  $_POST['password'] == ' ') {
                  $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
                  $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
                  $_SESSION['username'] = 'administrator';

                  echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
                   header('Refresh: 2; URL = adminform.php');

               }else {
                  $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
               }
            }
         ?>
      </div> <!-- /container -->

      <div class = "container" style="text-align: center;">

         <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" 
            action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
            ?>" method = "post">
            <h4 class = "form-signin-heading"><?php echo $msg; ?></h4>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "username" placeholder = "username = administrator" 
               required autofocus></br>
            <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
               name = "password" placeholder = "password = [spatie]" required><br>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
               name = "login">Login</button>
         </form>

         <form style="text-align:center;" action="menu.php">
             <button type="submit">Back to homepage</button>
             </form>
      </div> 

   </body>
</html>
```

adminform.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="adminform.css">
    <body>


<form style="text-align:center;" action="logout.php">
            <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
        <div class="connection">
                     <?php 
             session_start();

        //make connection
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

        //select db
        mysql_select_db('welkom');

        $sql="SELECT * FROM `abdijbieren`";

        $welkom = mysql_query($sql);



        ?>


            <h1>Abbey beer</h1>
            <table align="center" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
            <th>Tracking number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>

            <tr>


        <?php 
            while($abdijbieren=mysql_fetch_assoc($welkom)) {

                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>".$abdijbieren['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$abdijbieren['naam']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$abdijbieren['prijs']."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }//end while


            ?>
                </table>

        </div>
 <div class="php">
        <?php

    if ( ! empty($_POST))
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','welkom');

        if ($mysqli ->connect_error) 
        {
            die('connect error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren SET naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}' WHERE id={$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['volg'])};";

        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($insert)
        {
            echo "<span style='color:yellow;text-align:center;'>Update succesful!";
        }

        else
        {
            die("<span style='color:yellow;text-align:center;'>Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
                <br>
        </div>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Update</h1>

        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" action="">
            <input style="font-size:120%" name="track" type="text" placeholder="tracking number to select" required><br>
            <input style="font-size:120%" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name drink" required><br>
            (input style="font-size:120%" name="prijs" type="text" placeholder="prijs" required)<br>
            <input style="font-size:120%" type="submit" value="Update">
            </form>
        <?php

    if ( ! empty($_POST))
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','welkom');

        if ($mysqli ->connect_error) 
        {
            die('connect error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren SET prijs='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}'+' EUR ' WHERE id={$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['volg'])};";

        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($insert)
        {
            echo "<span style='color:yellow;text-align:center;'>Update succesful!";
        }

        else
        {
            die("<span style='color:yellow;text-align:center;'>Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <input style="font-size:120%" name="track" type="text" placeholder="tracking number to select" required><br>
            <input style="font-size:120%" name="prijs" type="text" placeholder="price" required><br>
            <input style="font-size:120%" type="submit" value="Update">
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION["username"]);
   unset($_SESSION["password"]);

   echo 'You just logged out.';
   header('Refresh: 2; URL = header.html');
?>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use my session in adminform.php. I do know what it is and it is very helpful when coding an administrative file, despite my lack of knowledge how to use it.

In `adminform.php`:

- I added `tracking number` in order to select the value within the colomn.
- There is also another problem in this code where I made multiple mysql-connections and sql's which lead to confusion for my program. Maybe because of the submits with the same value or something else.

It is very hard for me to create an administrative file for a website and I need help from you in order to improve. Any notice or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: Also why does one of your form elements look like `(input...` instead of `<input`?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.